# Can you remote debug an iOS Application via Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to remote debug an app I am using via TestFlight. I've looked around quite a bit to see if there is a way to do this, but haven't found any docs confirming or denying its existence.

Any experts know of a way to pull this off?

Comment: Is the device running the app jailbroken?

Comment: Nope Installed through TestFlight

Comment: There's likely no way then to run a remote debugger on it.